# Infection rate summation series in Python

Tags: python, loops

[image: infection rate summation formula]

I'm having trouble coding this up. Can somebody please help me?

The code when expanded would look like:

```
infection_0 = ((1 - )**0)*D[0]
infection_1 = ((1 - )**1)*D[0] + ((1 - )**0)*D[1]
infection_2 = ((1 - )**2)*D[0] + ((1 - )**1)*D[1] + D[2]
infection_3 = ((1 - )**3)*D[0] + ((1 - )**2)*D[1] + ((1 - )**1)*D[2] + D[3]
infection_4 = ((1 - )**4)*D[0] + ((1 - )**3)*D[1] + ((1 - )**2)*D[2] + ((1 - )**1)*D[3] + D[4]
...
```

where D is the number of cases at time n, and  = 1/14

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use sum

```
I[n] = sum([(1-)**(n-i)*D[i] for i in range(n+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def infection(iteration, y):
    base = 1-y
    res = 0
    for expo in range(iteration+1):
        idx = iteration - expo
        res += base**expo * D[idx]
    return res
```

Comment: no sorry. it doesn't check out

Comment: shouldn't it be  `res += base**i(teration-expo) * D[expo]`

Comment: doesn't check out